# How Object.prototype and bind() method work together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype, bind, factory

I'm reading about ngInfiniteScroll, and i'm a newbie about JS.
As I've read the [demo](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html) of nfInfiniteScroll, it's hard for me to understand why `Reddit.nextPage` have been transformed into `Reddit.prototype.nextPage` and it has been used the `bind()` method to wrap a part of `Reddit.prototype.nextPage` body.

Here is the code.

```
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope, Reddit) {
  $scope.reddit = new Reddit();
});

// Reddit constructor function to encapsulate HTTP and pagination logic
myApp.factory('Reddit', function($http) {
  var Reddit = function() {
    this.items = [];
    this.busy = false;
    this.after = '';
  };

  Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    if (this.busy) return;
    this.busy = true;

    var url = "https://api.reddit.com/hot?after=" + this.after + "&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK";
    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
      var items = data.data.children;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        this.items.push(items[i].data);
      }
      this.after = "t3_" + this.items[this.items.length - 1].id;
      this.busy = false;
    }.bind(this));
  };

  return Reddit;
});
```

I've just understood: by using `this` I can have access to properties in `Reddit` object.

Is it only because `var Reddit` is assigned an anonymous function and I need to bind `this` of the anonymous function to `this` of `Reddit.nextPage`, so they refer to the same properties?

But I can crearly see it is possible to have access to those properties even without the `bind()` method. See:

```
if (this.busy) return;
this.busy = true;
```

I've read some articles about the topic, but none exaplains it in depth: I'm really confused about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is context dependent. An example:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    console.log(this.baz);
  },
  baz: 3
};

foo.bar(); // logs 3
```

But in an asynchronous callback the context is gone, an example using `setTimeout`:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(this.baz); }, 0);
  },
  baz: 3
};

foo.bar(); // logs undefined or throws an error in strict mode
```

'this' is no longer in the context of foo. We can get around that limitation using `bind`:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    setTimeout((function() { console.log(this.baz); }).bind(this), 0);
  },
  baz: 3
};

foo.bar(); // logs 3
```

We've now bound the context to foo (the value of `this` at the call site) which is what's going on in your example, the binding of `this` in the callback passed to the success handler of the promise returned by `$http.jsonp`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at these functions:

```
Reddit.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    // outer function
    ...    
    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
      // inner function
    }.bind(this));
  };
```

Without binding, `this` in inner function would have different properties, since it's in another context. But if we call `bind(this)` we tell inner function to use `this` from **outer** function's context.

For more information I recommend [this article](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't visited the blog post, but I'm guessing that the reason it has been moved to be declared on the prototype is to have it automatically included in each instance of your "Reddit" service. Every time your service is created it will include this method, as all prototype methods are automatically inherited.

Regarding the bind, whenever you are passing a function as an argument, when the function is to get executed it will lose the main context, meaning it will not be bound to your Reddit service any more, because it will have a new scope of execution. Therefore calls to this.items, this.busy and this.after would all be undefined and would cause errors.

Here's some more info on the [bind(), call() and apply()](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations).